# How to participate in Uber Affiliate Program with oAuth

Tags: uber-api

According to Uber documentation a new user should be referred via:  "https://m.uber.com/sign-up?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"

So, is there a way to refer a new user using oAuth authentication with:
GET https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/authorize?

And shouldn't it be automatically referred since oAuth authorization requires client_id to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an application directs a new user to the OAuth authorization endpoint, `htts://login.uber.com/oauth/v1/authorize` and the user clicks "Sign Up" they will be taken to https://get.uber.com/go/?client_id=XXXXXX.

If the user creates an Uber account the `client_id` is recorded and the referral is tracked.